# How to generate an SVG of Highcharts graphics with images on the bars and show on the canvas tag?

Tags: svg, canvas, highcharts, canvg

I need get chart with images in bars (i using pattern and script Highstocks) and put in a tag Canvas, but when i send SVG to tag Canvas the images in bar disappear. Do you can help me? Follow bellow that i did until here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Posture/7aLzdej4/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Pattern Fill in Canvas</title>
    
            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    
    
            <!-- Highcharts -->
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
    
            <!-- Canvg -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvg/1.4/rgbcolor.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stackblur-canvas/1.4.1/stackblur.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvg/dist/browser/canvg.min.js"></script>
    
        </head>
        <body>
    
            <br>
            <div style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                <div id="graf-teste" style="min-width: 80%; height: 200px; max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                <button id='btn_capt'>Capturar Gráfico</button>
            </div>
    
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var redrawEnabled = true,
                ctr = 0;
                ctr1 = 1;
    
                Highcharts.chart('graf-teste', {
                // $('#graf-teste').highcharts({
                  chart: {
                    events: {
                      render: function() {
                        if (redrawEnabled) {
                          redrawEnabled = false;
                          var chart = this,
                            renderer = chart.renderer;
                          
                          chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(p) {
                            console.log(p);
                          
                            var widthRatio = p.shapeArgs.width / p.shapeArgs.height,
                              id = 'pattern-' + p.index + '-' + ctr;
    
                            var pattern = renderer.createElement('pattern').add(renderer.defs).attr({
                              width: 1,
                              height: widthRatio,
                              id: id,
                              patternContentUnits: 'objectBoundingBox'
                            });
    
                            renderer.image('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6c/38/66/6c38667a1977cbcac6f94b92decd7927.png', 0, 0, 1, widthRatio).attr({
                            }).add(pattern);
    
                            p.update({
                              color: 'url(#' + id + ')'
                            }, false);
                          });
    
                          chart.series[1].points.forEach(function(q) {
                            console.log(q);
                          
                            var widthRatio = q.shapeArgs.width / q.shapeArgs.height,
                              id = 'pattern-' + q.index + '-' + ctr1;
    
                            var pattern = renderer.createElement('pattern').add(renderer.defs).attr({
                              width: 1,
                              height: widthRatio,
                              id: id,
                              patternContentUnits: 'objectBoundingBox'
                            });
    
                            renderer.image('https://s2.glbimg.com/GFHUa5KeFPDTmwtAVjWl1A7oqTQ=/695x0/s.glbimg.com/po/tt2/f/original/2014/07/14/imagem0.jpg', 0, 0, 1, widthRatio).attr({
                            }).add(pattern);
    
                            q.update({
                              color: 'url(#' + id + ')'
                            }, false);
                          });
                                    
                          ctr++;
                          ctr1++;
                          chart.redraw();
                          redrawEnabled = true;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  title: {
                    text: 'Gráfico Teste'
                  },
                  exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                    categories: ['']
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }
    
                  },
                  legend: {
                    enabled: false
                  },
                  plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'percent',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.percentage:.0f}%</b>',
                            //point.percentage:.1f
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                        }
                    }
                 },
                  series: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    name: 'Serie 1',
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    // borderWidth: 1,
                    // borderColor: '#000000',
                    data: [250]
                  }, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    name: 'Serie 2',
                    enableMouseTracking: false,
                    // borderWidth: 1,
                    // borderColor: '#000000',
                    data: [100]
                  }],
                  credits: {
                    enabled: false
                  }
                });
            </script>
    
            <canvas id="graf"></canvas>
    
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#btn_capt").on('click',function(e){
    
                    var svg = $('#graf-teste').highcharts().getSVG();
                    canvg(document.getElementById('graf'),svg);
                    var img = graf.toDataURL("image/png"); //img is data:image/png;base64
                    img = img.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comments: It's totally necessary use highstock, because of others charts in page.

Comment: convert the images to data URLs

Comment: Robert Longson, how i do this? Do you can help me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#SVG

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u20c8vhL/

I created a new div for the chart and render the SVG there by this method:

```
$("#btn_capt").on('click', function(e) {

  var svg = chart.getSVG();

  $('#containerContainer').prepend(svg);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Wędzel, but now i have other problem kkkk, i trying save image of SVG in a folder for after load in other place; do you know how that i do this?

Comment: Is this an output that you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/raq5m397/

Comment: Thanks once more by your help! But i want pass datas by ajax and after save in a folder for example "/images".